# 1 passed and exactly 3 expected, Laravel

Tags: laravel, angular

Tengo un problema

estoy trabajando con angular y laravel y quiero pasar 2 parámetros aparte de la información pero me sale ese error, alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TS

```
this.personalservice.addhistorial(this.personal, this.id, this.user2).subscribe((data) => {
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.messageService.add({ key: 'error', severity: 'error', detail: 'Ocurrio un error' });
      });
```

service ts

```
addhistorial(data: any, id:any, user:any) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.URL}/addhistorial`, {data, id, user});
  }
```

controlador

```
public function addhistorial(Request $request, $id, $user){
        $personal = new Historial_personales();
        $personal->id_personal  = $id;
        $personal->id_user_cambio  = $user;
        $personal->id_empleado  = $request->input('id_empleado');
        $personal->plaza = $request->input('plaza');
        $personal->save();
}
```

router

```
 Route::post('addhistorial', 'personalController@addhistorial');
```

Comment: A tu ruta le hacen falta los parámetros para id y para user por eso el error, por que en su definición en el controlador le pasas dichos parámetros pero luego en la ruta no los vuelves a emplear o ¿de dónde esperas que obtenga dichos valores?

Comment: seria de esta forma? Route::post('addhistorial/{id}/{user}', 'personalController@addhistorial');

Comment: Prueba y nos avisas

Comment: lo acabo de hacer en la consola dice "net::ERR_FAILED" y problema de los CORS 
 pero en network no me da error alguno solo se pone en rojo el nombre de la ruta

Comment: Eso ya es un problema distinto, es decir tu pregunta ya fue resuelta y ahora tienes un problema de cors, busca aqui en la comunidad existen varias preguntas al respecto

Comment: pero no te ha pasado que a veces no es de CORS? lo digo porque ya tengo solucionado lo de CORS tengo otros métodos que hacen el get, post, put y sin problemas, pero cuando algo esta mal en alguna parte sale el problema de los CORS cuando no es de ahi, pero bueno, gracias!

Comment: Si consideras que el problema persiste a pesar de tener *solucionado lo de CORS*, entonces edita tu pregunta y déjala exponiendo este último mensaje de error que obtienes para que la comunidad pueda participar